# Create Landing page that render something instead of outlet when route is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-router

so I'm using React router for a project, and I need to render something on the landing page so it isn't just a blank page. But the component the app renders has an outlet, and I don't want to deal with making it invisible if the route is not empty. There must be a way to make it so the route displays content if there is any on the output and something else if the output is empty. What came to mind is a tertiary conditional, but i don't know how t make it work in this conditions.

The code structure is something like the following:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
     <div>
        {//Some code that has to display on every page here}
         <Outlet />
        {//Some code that has to display on every page here}
     </div>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the docs https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet

> `<Outlet>`
>
> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child routes are rendered. **If the parent route matched exactly, it will render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.**

More on `Index Routes` at https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#index-routes

So, you need to add an index route nested under the route for `App`.

```
// assuming the following is your route for App
<Route path="/" element={<App />}>
  // add the following index route
  <Route index element={
     <div>your landing content</div>
    } />
</Route>
```